# SPSS output: Change of direction between univariate and multivariate

Tags: spss

I am bit lost with my SPSS output. I am doing research on change management and its success factors. I set up a model with two IVs (kommunikation (communication) and Task Scoping). Alter, Geschlecht and Standort are just control variables.

When I look at the output, Model 1 and 2 make perfect sense to me but I am having a hard time interpreting the results of Model 3 for the IV Kommunikation.

In Model 2 the coefficient for Kommunikation is positive and significant (match my expectations). But in Model 3 the coefficient for Kommunikation is not significant anymore and all of a sudden negative (doesn't make much sense).

Can anybody help me out here and knows some possible explanations how to interpret this result?

Thanks!!

[image]

Comment: Can you say more about your situation, your variables, your data, your model, & your goals here? Are your variables categorical or continuous? Is `TaskScope` correlated with `Kommuikation`?

Comment: And _multivariate_ means you have more than one _dependent_ variable.

Comment: Try removing those variables that are not significant, starting with the least significant. Also, try building up models by only including significant variables. What SPSS routine is being used? How were these models selected? PCA or two-stage cluster analysis might be better for selecting models.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have done everything correctly (e.g. all the independent variables are continuous), what this means is that after controlling for task scope, communication has a negative relationship with the dependent variable (communication management).

That is, if you hold task scope constant, communication has an inverse relationship with communication management.

This sort of thing happens a lot, especially in observational studies where the independent variables are often related to each other.